# Python Django urls not working how they should?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

import main.views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', main.views.index, name="index"),
    path('story/', main.views.story, name="story"),
    path('haxs/', main.views.haxs, name="haxs"),
    path('contact/', main.views.contact, name="contact"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

.

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="story/">our story</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="haxs/">haxs</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact/">contact us</a></li>
```

I am working on a python django website and my urls are not working properly. I have included my urls.py and the nav links which are the same on each page. From home I can go to all the other pages and from the other pages I can go back to home.

My problem is when I go from for example: haxs to contact it does not work and the code url becomes "http://127.0.0.1:8000/haxs/story/" when it should just be "http://127.0.0.1:8000/story/" . It is like that with  our story/haxs/contact, I can not go between them pages. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply fix it by prepending url with `/`:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/story/">our story</a></li>
```

But better to use Django's [named url feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'story' %}">our story</a></li>
```

Comment: AHHH! This worked than you so much that's so annoying all I had to was add a forward slash, although I am using the Django way since it fits in better overall. Thank you so much :))

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @neverwalkaloner answer, I would recommend adding a namespaces to your urls. It helps with legibility because you can identify exactly from which app you're calling that url from.

I'm going to assume your app name is main.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

import main.views

    app_name = 'main' 
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', main.views.index, name="index"),
        path('story/', main.views.story, name="story"),
        path('haxs/', main.views.haxs, name="haxs"),
        path('contact/', main.views.contact, name="contact"),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main:story' %}">our story</a></li>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me but the above but did, thanks for the help though I appreciate it :)

Comment: Thats odd, you shouldnt have had a problem. This is something I personally do all the time because it has a cleaner feel. Definitely worth looking into. Ill provide a link! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Just change hrefs to relate with the server like this:

```
<a href={℅ url 'name of urls defined' ℅}>pagename</a>
```

{℅ url 'urls' ℅} is the django url variable to define app urls!